# How can I add vertical space between text and a minipage figure for all minipages?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm writing a instruction manual, I can't use figures because the images need to be directly underneath the step they are showing. To get the images to stay underneath the corresponding text, I am using the following code whenever I want to place an image.

```
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
    \vspace{5mm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{database}
    \captionof{figure}{Desktop icon of simulator app}
\end{minipage}
```

The thing that I don't like (as a programmer and a human) is that in order to get a vertical padding/space above the figure, I need to use vspace and specify the space every time.

Is there a way where I can configure all minipages to have the same vspace above them? And preferably not even include the vspace command in the minipage?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the `figure` environment, which has such a padding?

Comment: "I can't use figures because the images need to be directly underneath the step they are showing"

Comment: In this case a simple `center` environment should be enough. I don't see why a minipage, , and more particularly a minipage which is `\linewidth` wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d recommend that you do *not* redefine the `minipage` environment itself: you might still need the original version for something else.  Rather, define a command that does what you want, that is, it inserts an illustration with a caption.  As @Bernard [has remarked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384344/how-can-i-add-vertical-space-between-text-and-a-minipage-figure-for-all-minipage#comment951522_384344), there’s no actual need for a `minipage`: a `center` enviroment will do.  I make a tiny low-level customization to ensure that a page break does not occur right before the illustration: this could be achieved with the `enumitem` package too, but I’m somewhat reluctant to load the entire package just for this tiny adjustment…

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{mwe} % for this Minimal Working Example only

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\illustration[2]{%
    % keep illustration on the same page as preceding text:
    \begingroup
        \@beginparpenalty \@M
        \begin{center}%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}%
            \captionof{figure}{#2}%
        \end{center}%
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\illustration{image-a}{The letter~``A''}
\lipsum[2]
\illustration{image-b}{The letter~``B''}
\lipsum[2]
\illustration{image-c}{The letter~``C''}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**  On second thought, a `minipage` environment *is* needed, because of how the `\captionof` command is implemented, in order to avoid a possible page break between the image and its caption.  The following is a different solution that takes this issue into account:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{mwe} % for this Minimal Working Example only

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\illustration[2]{%
    \par % end previous paragraph (if necessary)
    \addpenalty{\@M}% prohibit page break
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}% or "\medskipamount"...
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}%
        \captionof{figure}{#2}%
    \end{minipage}\par
    \addpenalty{-\@lowpenalty}%
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\illustration{image-a}{The letter~``A''}
\lipsum[2]
\illustration{image-b}{The letter~``B''}
\lipsum[2]
\illustration{image-c}{The letter~``C''}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

for space before mini pages you not need to change `minipage` definition. with help of `etoolbox` macro `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` you can add desired space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{etoolbox}                               % <---
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minipage}{\par\vspace{5mm}} % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{database}
    \captionof{figure}{Desktop icon of simulator app}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `minipage` environment to include that `vspace` you need by the following three lines:

```
\let\oldminipage=\minipage
\let\endoldminipage=\endminipage
\renewenvironment{minipage}{\vspace{5mm}\begin{oldminipage}}{\end{oldminipage}}
```

I've included an example of my own since you didn't provide one. Here is the output of the original `minipage` and the re-defined one for comparison. In case you temporarily need the original behavior back, just use `\begin{oldminipage} .. \end{oldminipage}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

Some text here ...

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{database}
    \captionof{figure}{Desktop icon of simulator app}
\end{minipage}

\let\oldminipage=\minipage
\let\endoldminipage=\endminipage
\renewenvironment{minipage}{\vspace{5mm}\begin{oldminipage}}{\end{oldminipage}}

\bigskip
Some text here ...

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{database}
    \captionof{figure}{Desktop icon of simulator app}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]